# LEFT JOIN not joining the second table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join

I'm having a problem with my SQL command running on MariaDB.

I have the following tables:

**reservations**:

| id | child_id | time_from | time_to | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-17 13:20:00 | 2021-05-17 14:20:00 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-19 08:00:00 | 2021-05-19 12:30:00 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-05-14 10:00:00 | 2021-05-14 13:00:00 | NULL |

**users**:

| id | email | role | name | surname | contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | one@email.com | admin | peter | peterson | 123456789 |
| 3 | two@email.com | assistant | john | johnson | NULL |
| 4 | three@email.com | admin | mike | mikeson | 987654321 |
| 5 | four@email.com | admin | leo | leoson | NULL |
| 6 | five@email.com | admin | jane | janeson | NULL |

I'm trying to join those tables by the `reservations.user_id` and `users.id` using `LEFT JOIN`, however unsuccessfully.

This is the command I made and edited many times without success:

```sql
SELECT reservations.*, IF(DATE_FORMAT(reservations.time_from, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE(), IF(reservations.user_id IS NULL, TRUE, FALSE), TRUE) AS removable FROM reservations
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT users.id AS userID, users.name AS name, users.surname AS surname FROM users
) AS users ON reservations.user_id = users.userID
WHERE reservations.time_from >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY reservations.time_from;
```

However this is all I'm getting:

| id | child_id | time_from | time_to | user_id | removable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-05-14 10:00:00 | 2021-05-14 13:00:00 | NULL | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-17 13:20:00 | 2021-05-17 14:20:00 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-19 08:00:00 | 2021-05-19 12:30:00 | 2 | 1 |

Basically I'm getting the first table without the data of the second table.

I do need to include rows with `user_id NULL` as it is used for confirmation reasons. Am I missing something?

Here is the requested dbfiddle: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d3de828b24c4219e65c065d00ae40c3e)

The column is `users.id` but in the `LEFT JOIN SELECT` query I rename the column to `userID`. `user_id` of the reservation is a column allowing NULL, as it is a user assigned for the reservation. NULL => no one has been assigned yet.

What I'm trying to do is to get all the reservation rows and users assigned by staff to the reservation. Imagine it as assigned guard for the child. That's why I need to get all upcoming reservations with information who the guard is going to be.

If the `user_id` is not NULL, the table should contain even the columns `users.name` and `users.surname` since I'm selecting them in the join. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clarification in the fiddle you provided, the only other way I can interpret your issue is you're saying you're not seeing the columns for the `users` table even though you joined to it. That's because you didn't list any columns from the `users` table in the `SELECT` list.

You can add any or all columns from your `users` subquery you want to the `SELECT` list like so:

```
SELECT reservations.*, IF(DATE_FORMAT(reservations.time_from, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE(), IF(reservations.user_id IS NULL, TRUE, FALSE), TRUE) AS removable,
    users.*
FROM reservations
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT users.id AS userID, users.name AS name, users.surname AS surname FROM users
) AS users ON reservations.user_id = users.userID
WHERE reservations.time_from >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY reservations.time_from;
```

Note you shouldn't use `*` in your `SELECT` list as it's bad practice and can lead to dependency issues later on, and rather you should explicitly list the column names you want.

Furthermore it seems like you might've gotten a little confused because you used a subquery to join in the `users` table but that's not necessary, rather you can re-write your query simpler like this:

```
SELECT reservations.*, IF(DATE_FORMAT(reservations.time_from, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE(), IF(reservations.user_id IS NULL, TRUE, FALSE), TRUE) AS removable,
    users.id AS userID, users.name AS name, users.surname AS surname
FROM reservations
LEFT JOIN users
    ON reservations.user_id = users.id
WHERE reservations.time_from >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY reservations.time_from;
```

Comment: Right! Yes, great! Thank you, that's the piece I was missing :)

Comment: @Nejento Great, no problem! Also I slid in one more update that simplifies your query too. 

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I'm getting the first table without the data of the second table.

Basically, that is the *feature* that `LEFT` provides.

Remove `LEFT` and see if you get what you expected.

Also, simplify the query as J.D. suggested.